# GSA - enable optional HTTPS?

Tags: https, google-search-appliance

Is there a way on a Google Search Appliance to enable optional https?

Under settings, under the heading ***Force secure connections when serving*** the options are:

- No.
- Use HTTPS when serving secure results, but not when serving public results.
- Use HTTPS when serving both public and secure results.

I don't want to Force secure connections though, I want them to be optional.
ie, if someone requests the site as HTTP it serves as HTTP and if they request it as HTTPS it serves as HTTPS.

If I choose the 1st or 2nd options it accepts connections on HTTPS but immediately redirects to HTTP (ie, it forces HTTP). And the 3rd option forces HTTPS.

Is there any other settings that would enable it to accept HTTPS optionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must install a valid ssl certificate or create a self-signed certificate. (Administration->SSL Settings)
2. In SSL Settings->Other Settings->"Force secure connections when serving?" you must select either: 'a' or 'b'

   a. "Use HTTPS when serving secure results, but not when serving public
   results."

   b. "Use HTTPS when serving both public and secure results."

Unless all requests are coming from https, chances are you will select 'a'.

If 'b' is selected, you will receive an "unknown error" if sending query over standard http.

Now here's the major caveat:

Your observation that https still redirects to http, even with 'a' selected, is correct. The only method that I am aware of to force SSL when serving results with option 'a' is to send the additional 'access' query parameter '**&access=a**'

'a'=all

'p'=public (default)

https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1087053

**BEWARNED**: Depending on how your GSA is configured, there may be privacy implications if your organization maintains public collections containing private urls requiring authentication. URLS that require auth will be served right along with the rest of your results.

Comment: marking this as the answer since it's the closest thing. appending &access=a does force the connection to https so I suppose I could use this to selectively use https ... wasn't really what I was looking for but it seems the GSA just doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the settings you mention to "No" will cause the GSA to use whatever protocol you started the experience with to be used.

Choosing the other options will cause the GSA to switch protocols.

**Edit** - It looks like this not possible.  It doesn't matter what you request, the GSA will redirect based on the config.

Comment: That is not true. I set it to No and it still accepts connections on HTTPS and immediately responds with a 302 to HTTP.

Comment: You're right.  I tested again.  The no, forces http for all requests and actually redirects.

Answer (score -1):

If you create an SSL certificate for your GSA's host name and install the valid SSL certificate then it should serve results on port 443 (HTTPS) correctly.

i.e. if your GSA is "search.mydomain.com" then create a properly signed SSL certificate in that name and install to the GSA.

Typically this works without a certificate but the browser will show a warning message due to no SSL certificate / invalid SSL certificate.

Comment: I have purchased a SSL cert from a trusted CA and installed it on the GSA.

The GSA accepts HTTPS connections but responds immediately with a redirect to HTTP. The browser does not throw an error on processing the redirect and the cert is properly served (albeit briefly.) My problem is not the cert but the fact that it forces all traffic to HTTP by immediately redirecting HTTPS traffic to HTTP.